# HTML Page not scrolling

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to HTML and I decided to make a small sign up page as practice. For some reason, it won't scroll (There is no scrollbar and it just cuts off at the bottom of the screen). The HTML code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/7sukbe0t/1/. I have a hunch that the reason for the problem is

```
table-layout:fixed
```

but without that line, I'm unable to get my column sizes to be of equal size. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the code from that jdFiddle there's an orphan `</ol>`

Comment: @SERPRO thanks for pointing it out, removed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the table position to:

**relative**

```
<table style="width:300px; min-height: 100px; position:relative; top:300px; left:200px; table-layout:fixed;">
```

or

**absolute**

```
<table style="width:300px; min-height: 100px; position:absolute; top:300px; left:200px; table-layout:fixed;">
```

Edit:

Check these out to see the differences between the `position` values

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

http://www.yorku.ca/nmw/facs1939f13/week02/css_relVSabsVSfixed.html

Answer (score 1):

You should change the position to relative instead of fixed, like so:

```
<table style="width:300px; position:relative; top:300px; left:200px; table-layout:fixed;">
```